# Totally forgotten how to do this with regular expression

Tags: c#, regex, io

I want to loop through the lines on a file, and match as regular expression of ID'd to each line.

Then when there is a match I want to print the line number followed by the actual match.

So:

```
string folderToSearch = @"C:\Projects\Unilever\Database";
string idsToMacthAsRegexp = "1943|3937";
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(folderToSearch);
FileInfo[] filesToSearch = dir.GetFiles("*.sql", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

foreach (FileInfo f in filesToSearch)
{
    string line;

    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(f.FullName))
    {
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {

            if (Regex.IsMatch(line, idsToMacthAsRegexp))
            {

                // I want to print the portion that matches but cant
                // even remember what this is called, or how to do it!

            }
        } 
    }
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: The `Matches(input, regex_pattern)` method from `Regex` class does return all matched occurences of a pattern as a list of `Match` objects. Is that what you're missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `Regex.Match` method instead of `Regex.IsMatch`. That will return a `Match` object which lets you check the `Success` property, then refer to the matched value:

```
Match m = Regex.Match(line, idsToMacthAsRegexp);
if (m.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
}
```

As for the line numbers, that has nothing to do with the regex (unless that is something you're matching, but that doesn't seem to be the case from your pattern). For that perhaps you want to declare a counter variable outside of your loop, set to zero, and increment it on every pass of the loop (right after the `while` statement).

Answer (score 0):

Especially if there could be more than matched item or you have groups:

- Use `Match` instead of `IsMatch`
- Lookp through `Groups` collection of the match object
- Use `Index` and `Length` to find the value